# Error en petición de api rest flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Realizo la petición de la siguiente manera

```
final url = Uri.http(_baseUrl, 'api/ProductoTerminado/ListaProductos');
      final resp =
          await http.get(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
      print(resp.body);
```

al imprimirla si me resuelve y marca la siguiente respuesta
`[{"ot":"1           ","pedido":"1         ","posicion":1,"sociedad":"1   ","numeroCliente":"1         ","cliente":"1                                  ","pieza":"1  ","codigoMaterial":"1                 ","producto":"1                                       ","cantidad":1.99,"importe":1,"fecha":"2022-01-18T00:00:00"},{"ot":"2           ","pedido":"300399    ","posicion":30,"sociedad":"M3M ","numeroCliente":"3050      ","cliente":"TUBOS DE ACERO DE MEXICO S.A.      ","pieza":"2  ","codigoMaterial":"40152             ","producto":"PLACA BASE CIRCULAR 3T DE 2800 DIAMETRO ","cantidad":2.01,"importe":231406.48,"fecha":"2022-01-18T00:00:00"}]`

cuando trato de mapear a mi datos me marca un error en la siguiente linea

`final Map<String, dynamic> userMap = json.decode(resp.body);`

y en consola marca lo siguiente

`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

ya lo he revisado y busque y en la linea donde hago el json decode sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resp.body` es una lista como tienes en el `print`. Cambia el código

```
final Map<String, dynamic> userMap = json.decode(resp.body);
```

Por

```
final List<dynamic> userList = json.decode(resp.body);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa era solución